# Rewriting files with BufferedWriter and FileWriter libraries

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a game and I'm having an tough time overwriting save files. I've seen how to clear a file and then rewrite it later on, but I would like something that has the capability to just overwrite the file. I am using BufferedWriter and FileWriter libraries. Heres the code I'm using:

```
    System.out.println("Congratulations! You beat the first maze! Thanks for playing!\nBefore you go, please answer this one question.");
    System.out.println("Please enter a color of the following choices.\nBlack, Navy, Dark Gray, Gray, Light Gray, Purple, Olive, Pink, White, or\nYellow.");
    String fave = kb.nextLine();
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile("colorchoice.txt"),true));
        writer.write(fave);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) { /*ignore*/ }
    }
    try {
        writer.flush();
        writer.setLength(0);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("save.txt"), true));
        writer.write(name);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write(choice4);
        writer.newLine();
        if (choice == 1 || choice == 2) {
            writer.write(gender2);
            writer.newLine();
        }
        writer.write(col);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.write(dead2);
        writer.newLine();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) { /*ignore*/ }
    }
    System.exit(0);
```

Ignoring the println statement, is there anything I can do in BufferedWriter or FileWriter to overwrite the file? or will I need to change what imports I have to some other library to get overwriting to work?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The second parameter to the [`FileWriter` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)) is `append`. You have that set to `true` which will add to the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile("colorchoice.txt"),true));
```

Change `true` to `false` in the `append` parameter.